# pgfplots: changing shape of axis tick marks

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

How can I use different shaped tick marks on the axis, e.g. circles? I've tried setting the tick style to `shape=circle` and similar things, but it seems to have no effect.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[tick style={shape=circle}]
    \addplot[samples=300,domain=0:1,thick]{x^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove the default tick marks with `xtick style={draw=none}` and plot the circles on the x-axis with another `\addplot` command using `mark=o` to make the circle.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
%   tick style={shape=circle},
   xtick style={draw=none}, % <-- removing default tick marks
   ymin=-0.1                % <-- define ymin
   ]
    \addplot[samples=300,domain=0:1,thick]{x^2};
    \addplot[draw=none,mark=o] coordinates
    {(0,-0.1) (0.2,-0.1) (0.4,-0.1) (0.6,-0.1) (0.8,-0.1) (1,-0.1)}; % <-- add circles by plotting marks at y=-0.1
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Was hoping for an automatic way to do it, but this does the job. Thanks